# Javascript why is this false? 10 > 9 > 8 === true;

Tags: javascript

Simple JS question: 10 > 9 > 8 === true; returns false.

Can somebody please elaborate and explain?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Its not comparing right way

Comment: You are comparing 3 values, in which the first two (10 and 9) would return a boolean: hence a 1/0 value would be compared with 8, which would be false in both cases, hence false === true; is false.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Please find answer Below:

```
10 > 9 > 8 === true;
```

The > operator has a higher precedence than === and is left-to-right associative. If we add the implicit parentheses we get this:

```
((10 > 9) > 8) === true;
```

This evaluates further to:

```
((10 > 9) > 8) === true;
(true > 8) === true;
(1 > 8) === true;
false === true;
false;
```